Predicting cost for several options and then choosing the cheapest option
I created an ML model that predicts the cost of shipping an order in our online store.
For each order placed, there is a variable number of methods (up to 10) available to ship. So for one order, there may be methods M1, M2, and M3 available, but for another order, there may be methods M1 and M5 available.  Only one method will be chosen by our software, and the shipping cost is unknown ahead of time.
Using a separate training set, validation set, and test set, where historical costs are known, I found that the model has a high MAE compared to the mean order cost. I then used this model to predict costs for orders in my test set on ship methods that were not used.  I then looked at the potential savings by assuming that the cheapest predicted method was selected and comparing it to the known order cost.
Because the MAE was high, I'd like to understand with some sort of confidence how much money we can expect to save. Can someone please guide me as to what would be an appropriate statistical way to determine this?

Does your cost model produce any sort of standard error or confidence interval?

@dimitriy Sorry for the dumb question, is the standard error the same as the root mean squared error?  If so, then yes, I have that.  If not, I'm guessing I  can compute it (with guidance) as I have access to the entire test set and every prediction.

Some statistical/ML procedures produce an estimated cost plus some measure of uncertainty around that estimate (standard error, confidence interval, prediction interval, margin of error). If you add some details in your question about what sort of model you used, I can try to give more practible advice.

I used AWS canvas which hides a lot of the details about the model itself since it tries a bunch of different types behind the scenes.  The only overall error metrics it gave me were the MAE, MSE, RMSE, and R2.

So I am assuming that you are interested in total( ie sum)  cost saving .
this can be analysed as the average over orders of (cheapest predicted cost - actual cost)
saving = (actual cost - model cost ) = actual cost - (model predicted cost  + prediction error)
then the average saving = average(actual cost) - average(model predicted cost) + average (error)  ( I am guessing yoour average error on the test set is not exactly zero!)
the variance of the saving = variance(actual cost - model predicted cost) + variance (error)
the standard error of the average saving per order is $\sqrt{\frac{ \text{variance of the saving}}{N}}$ assuming the orders are independent
assuming you have a large enough sample (i'd assume you are talking in the 1000's?) and/or your data is not too far from normal, the average should be close to normally distributed (by the central limit theorem), so you can get confidence intervals on that average cost saving.
https://onlinestatbook.com/mobile/estimation/mean.html
I think the fundamental doubt about this is whether the orders are independent. eg say in your test set you only ship to one location, then the average order has the same variability as a single order. These sort of issues can be solved, but they first have to be identified...

Thanks, I'll try this out and respond back.  Yes, orders in the test set are in the tens of thousands.  Orders are independent in the sense that given one order in the test set, afaik, there's no (or very little) correlation to the next order as to any of the order features.  I just took a randomized sample without replacement from the entire data set and made that the test set.
